# how to create timestamp with interval 50 second in javasricpt

Tags: javascript, timestamp

### i want create timestamps with interval 50 second

example:

$start = '2017-10-20 10:51:00';
$end = '2017-10-20 10:56:00';

2017-10-20 10:51:00,
 
2017-10-20 10:51:50,
2017-10-20 10:52:40,
 
2017-10-20 10:53:30,
2017-10-20 10:54:20,
2017-10-20 10:55:10,
2017-10-20 10:56:00

Comment: So after you read up on [the JS `Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and its methods, where did you get stuck?

Comment: i can't loop from $start to $end with interval